# webduino mac address what is the correct format

Tags: arduino, webduino

Using `webduino` library, the `Web_HelloWorld` example has the following:

```
// CHANGE THIS TO YOUR OWN UNIQUE VALUE
static uint8_t mac[6] = { 0x02, 0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0x00, 0x22 };
```

What's with the `0x02` etc? If my mac address is `90-A2-DA...` do I simply change the line of code to be...

```
static uint8_t mac[6] = { 90, A2, DA, ... };
```

? Or do I need to keep the format of the `x`'s? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should keep the "0x" prefix, which specifies the value to be hexadecimal. For example, if you just gave it "90", it would assume a decimal, base-10 90 instead of a hexadecimal 90.

```
static uint8_t mac[6] = { 0x90, 0xA2, 0xDA, ... };
```